# .Net Core Startup.cs (no third party container) Dependency Injection Using Reflection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependencies

.Net Core Dependenct Injection using Reflection. Can i do something like below.

Error: Showing Visual Stuido designer
ICandidateService is type, is not valid in given context.

Please suggest, can we do this using third party containers.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            { 
               var candidateService = ServiceInstance.GetService<ICandidateService>(
                    new FactoryModel()
                    {
                        Connection = "User ID=postgres;Password=123;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Test12;Pooling=true;",
                        DLLCulture = "Culture=neutral",
                        DLLRef = "EF.Service.SQL",
                        DLLVer = "Version=1.0.0.0",
                        ServiceType = ServiceTypes.PostgreSQL
                    }
                );


               services.AddScoped(ICandidateService)(candidateService);


    }


//Service Instance Class
public static class ServiceInstance
    { 
        public static T GetService<T>(FactoryModel factoryModel)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(factoryModel.Connection) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(factoryModel.DLLRef) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(factoryModel.DLLVer) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(factoryModel.DLLCulture))
                throw new NullReferenceException("Missing dataType or connection string");

            return GetSQLServiceIntance<T>(factoryModel);
        }

        public static T GetSQLServiceIntance<T>(FactoryModel factoryModel)
        { 
            Type responseContract = GetSQLServiceType<T>(factoryModel);

            object serviceInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(responseContract, factoryModel.Connection, factoryModel.ServiceType.ToString());
            T thisService = (T)serviceInstance;
            return thisService;

        }

        public static Type GetSQLServiceType<T>(FactoryModel factoryModel)
        {
            var requestContract = typeof(T).Name.Remove(0, 1);
            string typeName = $"{factoryModel.DLLRef}.{requestContract}, {factoryModel.DLLRef}, {factoryModel.DLLVer}, {factoryModel.DLLCulture}";

            Type responseContract = Type.GetType(typeName);

            return  responseContract;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
services.AddScoped(ICandidateService)(candidateService);
```

write

```
services.AddSingletone<ICandidateService>(candidateService);
```

if you want to have only one pre-created instance,

or make a factory-Func if you need `Scoped` lifetime:

```
services.AddScoped<ICandidateService>(_ => ServiceInstance.GetService<ICandidateService>(new FactoryModel() {...}));
```

Comment: i get swiggley reg line under candidateService and the error is. Argument 2: cannot convert from ICandidateService to 'System.Func<System.IServiceProvider, ICandidateService>'

Comment: Good, now we have concrete error :) Now, main question is - do you want to have `Scoped` service (why you are registering pre-created instance which always the same?) or `Singleton` ?

Comment: Depending on FactoryModel (above code) which i have hardcoded there (in reality that comes from appsettings.json) and connects to different ICustomerService instances depending on the repository type. Yes you are right i guess i can do Singleton.

Comment: Decide on lifetime and change registration to one or other. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much Dmitry, that worked and is excellent answer. Tahnk you

Comment: Grey (green after click) V-sign and upvote triangle on the left are correct "stackoverflow-style" way to thank for the answer ;)